# Where can I find documentation about Nutch status codes?

Tags: nutch

Nutch has a couple of status codes which are used to classify crawled documents.

Examples of codes which Nutch uses are:

```
db_unfetched
db_fetched
db_gone
db_redir_perm
db_redir_temp
db_notmodified
```

Where can I find a clear explanation what the codes means?

Reading forum posts and answerers here at Stackoverflow gives a good understanding of the codes. Also this page gives some good input: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/CrawlDatumStates But I'm looking for a page which describes the meaning of each status code.

Comment: Google and Bing are both excellent at searching for things and returning links to the results. "Shopping list" questions ("Please post a list of things for me") are not appropriate here. There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. Voting to close as "not constructive". Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess the question should have ask whats the meaning of the different statuses instead of asking for a reference to a page where I can find the answer. I would not consider this question to be shopping list question, just a badly formed question since I'm still looking for one correct answer.

Comment: The question asks "Where can I find...?" in the subject, and the body says "Where can I find...?", and there's no possible answer to those questions other than links to where you can find things. I'm sorry, but it's clearly a shopping list question.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Sorry for an ill formed question.

Comment: I understand it is an old question. unfortunately, nutch did not have provide proper documentation related to the states till now ... I have given few detailed use cases what these status flags are..... check this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63791392/nutch-can-anyone-explain-what-are-status-name-indicates-in-readdb-stats/63880833#63880833 ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official documentation but I could pull this one from the [CrawlDatum](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/trunk/src/java/org/apache/nutch/crawl/CrawlDatum.java?view=markup) class:

```
  /** Page was not fetched yet. */
  public static final byte STATUS_DB_UNFETCHED      = 0x01;

  /** Page was successfully fetched. */
  public static final byte STATUS_DB_FETCHED        = 0x02;

  /** Page no longer exists. */
  public static final byte STATUS_DB_GONE           = 0x03;

  /** Page temporarily redirects to other page. */
  public static final byte STATUS_DB_REDIR_TEMP     = 0x04;

  /** Page permanently redirects to other page. */
  public static final byte STATUS_DB_REDIR_PERM     = 0x05;

  /** Page was successfully fetched and found not modified. */
  public static final byte STATUS_DB_NOTMODIFIED    = 0x06;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I thought that there is no official documentation for the statuses and thanks for the reference to the code. I would consider STATUS_DB_FETCHED to also be flagged for re-crawl since pages which ha been fetch may have STATUS_DB_FETCHED, Is that right?