# Nutch can anyone explain what are status name indicates in readdb stats

Tags: nutch

Nutch can anyone explain what are status name indicates in readdb stats.

1.db_redir_perm
2.db_unfetched
3.db_fetched
4.db_Gone
5.db_redir_temp
6.db_duplicate
7.db_notmodified.

Comment: I have gone through documentation not able to find this.

Answer (score 2):

Nutch store all the metadata information of URLs in [CrawlDatum](https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.16/org/apache/nutch/crawl/CrawlDatum.html) Object. and it is stored in `/crawldb/*/part-*/data` location

As per the source code of CrawlDatum

```
 /** Page was not fetched yet. */
   db_unfetched -->   public static final byte STATUS_DB_UNFETCHED = 0x01; 
      /** Page was successfully fetched. */
   db_fetched -->   public static final byte STATUS_DB_FETCHED = 0x02;
      /** Page no longer exists. */
   db_Gone -->   public static final byte STATUS_DB_GONE = 0x03;
      /** Page temporarily redirects to other page. */
   db_redir_temp -->   public static final byte STATUS_DB_REDIR_TEMP = 0x04;
      /** Page permanently redirects to other page. */
   db_redir_perm -->   public static final byte STATUS_DB_REDIR_PERM = 0x05;
      /** Page was successfully fetched and found not modified. */
   db_notmodified -->   public static final byte STATUS_DB_NOTMODIFIED = 0x06;
      /** Page was marked as being a duplicate of another page */
   db_duplicate -->   public static final byte STATUS_DB_DUPLICATE = 0x07;
```

**CrawlDatum** `private byte status;` will take one of the values mentioned above depending on the state of URL. (and there are lot of other flags which i'm not discussing now)

**When will status value of CrawlDatum(object) change?**

There are a lot of flows where it might take one of the several states mentioned above.I will explain a few flows which I'm well aware of.

1. when we inject URLs into nutch. crawlDb folder is created with each URL CrawlDatum object  with state as  (db_unfetched). see below code from Injector class

[InjectReducer](https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.3/org/apache/nutch/crawl/Injector.InjectReducer.html#reduce(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,%20java.util.Iterator,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector,%20org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter)).reduce method.

```
for (CrawlDatum val : values) {
    if (val.getStatus() == CrawlDatum.STATUS_INJECTED) {
      injected.set(val);
      injected.setStatus(CrawlDatum.STATUS_DB_UNFETCHED);
      injectedSet = true;
    } else {
      old.set(val);
      oldSet = true;
    }
  }
```

By setting this flag it will be helpful for the generator phase to pick only unfetched urls.

2. In Fetcher phase if you open [FetcherThread](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/java/org/apache/nutch/fetcher/FetcherThread.java) source code. crawlDatum status is changed based on url http stats code. you can refer http codes [here](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html). (for better understanding)

> ```
> case ProtocolStatus.MOVED: // redirect
>     case ProtocolStatus.TEMP_MOVED:
>       int code;
>       boolean temp;
>       if (status.getCode() == ProtocolStatus.MOVED) {
>         code = CrawlDatum.STATUS_FETCH_REDIR_PERM;
>         temp = false;
>       } else {
>         code = CrawlDatum.STATUS_FETCH_REDIR_TEMP;
>         temp = true;
>       }
>       output(fit.url, fit.datum, content, status, code);
>       String newUrl = status.getMessage();
>       Text redirUrl = handleRedirect(fit, newUrl, temp,
>           Fetcher.PROTOCOL_REDIR);
>       if (redirUrl != null) {
>         fit = queueRedirect(redirUrl, fit);
>       } else {
>         // stop redirecting
>         redirecting = false;
>       }
>       break;
>     case ProtocolStatus.EXCEPTION:
>       logError(fit.url, status.getMessage());
>       int killedURLs = ((FetchItemQueues) fetchQueues).checkExceptionThreshold(fit
>           .getQueueID());
>       if (killedURLs != 0)
>         context.getCounter("FetcherStatus",
>             "AboveExceptionThresholdInQueue").increment(killedURLs);
>       /* FALLTHROUGH */
>     case ProtocolStatus.RETRY: // retry
>     case ProtocolStatus.BLOCKED:
>       output(fit.url, fit.datum, null, status,
>           CrawlDatum.STATUS_FETCH_RETRY);
>       break;
>     case ProtocolStatus.GONE: // gone
>     case ProtocolStatus.NOTFOUND:
>     case ProtocolStatus.ACCESS_DENIED:
>     case ProtocolStatus.ROBOTS_DENIED:
>       output(fit.url, fit.datum, null, status,
>           CrawlDatum.STATUS_FETCH_GONE);
>       break;
>     case ProtocolStatus.NOTMODIFIED:
>       output(fit.url, fit.datum, null, status,
>           CrawlDatum.STATUS_FETCH_NOTMODIFIED);
>       break;
>     default:
>       if (LOG.isWarnEnabled()) {
>         LOG.warn("{} {} Unknown ProtocolStatus: {}", getName(),
>             Thread.currentThread().getId(), status.getCode());
>       }
>       output(fit.url, fit.datum, null, status,
>           CrawlDatum.STATUS_FETCH_RETRY);
> ```

```
    if (redirecting && redirectCount > maxRedirect) {
      ((FetchItemQueues) fetchQueues).finishFetchItem(fit);
      if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
        LOG.info("{} {} - redirect count exceeded {}", getName(),
            Thread.currentThread().getId(), fit.url);
      }
      output(fit.url, fit.datum, null,
          ProtocolStatus.STATUS_REDIR_EXCEEDED,
          CrawlDatum.STATUS_FETCH_GONE);
    }
```

3. In deduplication phase if a URLs is found to be duplicate based on md5 hash then it will mark the status as **STATUS_DB_DUPLICATE** in the deduplication phase and in the next iteration it will not be picked by the **Generator**.

Comment: what is differnce between in db_fetched and db_notmodified.  for example  if i inject dupicate urls in nutch.